# How to add opencv in python form server?

Tags: python, opencv

I want to run my programs in server but when I type import cv2 in that it says 'No module Named cv2' I know the directory of opencv is: '/share/apps/opencv'.
how can I add this path to my program? (Notice I can't install anything in server and also using sudo is forbidden)

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you using PaaS cloud service?

Comment: It's for our university and we access it via ssh.

Comment: what linux distro you are using it with?

Comment: The distribution of server is centos and mine is ubuntu

Comment: this `opencv` can be C/C++ library and you may need Python wrapper for this library. Ask server admin to install required elements.

Comment: I asked and he said they are installed.

Comment: did you asked for `opencv` or Python module `cv2` ? If Python module `cv2` is really installed they you need only `import cv2` ?

Comment: No, but I think they should be exist in /share/apps/opencv/build

Comment: `cv2` should be in `/.../python2.7/...` folder - for Python 2.7. Or `/.../python3.5/...` for Python 3.5

Answer (score 0):

First of all install opencv in CentOS
Opencv can be install in CentOS in two ways:

1) Install from available yum repository.
 opencv-2.4.13 repository are available. If you need latest version of opencv then go for 2. option.

2) Opencv installation from source.

**Install opencv from yum repo**

Before installation of opencv-python from yum repository we have to install require library numpy.

```
$ sudo yum install python-devel python-nose python-setuptools gcc gcc-gfortran gcc-c++ blas-devel lapack-devel atlas-devel
$ sudo easy_install pip
$ sudo pip install numpy==1.6.1
```

now opencv will be available for installation.

```
$ yum install opencv
```

**Optional Dependencies:**

> Install below pakcages if you need latest libraries of PNG, JPEG,
>   JPEG2000, TIFF, WebP.

```
$ yum install libpng-devel libjpeg-turbo-devel jasper-devel openexr-devel libtiff-devel libwebp-devel
```

**Verify Installation:**

```
$ python
>>> import cv2
>>> print cv2.__version__
```

Also, if openCV is already installed using source files, then make sure that source installation will install package in /usr/local/lib . To use this we need to copy site-packages from /usr/local/lib to /usr/lib.

> Move opencv module from in defult python path:

```
$ cp /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Comment: can you do `print cv2.__file__` to show OP where he can find files ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply but,I can't use yum install because it needs sudo. and in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages I can't find cv2.so

Comment: then try installing it from source, refer here , http://techieroop.com/install-opencv-in-centos/